# Remove 0 from s.no in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, numbers

I add S.No in crystal report through database and when i add S.No field in report this show 0 at the end like this

```
1.00
2.00
3.00
4.00
```

and so on

so how i remove this when i left click on field i found these options

```
Format object
highlight expert
Browse field data
Select expert
insert
move
copy
delete
paste
```

check this image

[image]

[image]
So how i remove this 0 from serial number ?

Comment: if is fine if you convert the resultant to string format from number then you can try `ToText(Field,0,"")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on that field and Go to `Format_Field..` --> `Numbers`

[image]

You can also make these changes in Format Object. Otherwise you can create a formula:

```
@sno_number = tonumber(<RowNumber>);
```

Then use sno_number in place of S.NO.

Comment: there is no format field option .. and in that format object there is only common,border,font  , paragraph, hyperlink options @ankur

Comment: Can you share the screen short of that report?

Comment: i select exact database field

Comment: in store procedure i add line line to create s.no.. select Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))  AS 'RowNumber',

Comment: ok.. it is taking your field as text not number.. that's why you are facing problem..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121921/discussion-between-ankur-and-user6628729).

Comment: but why we create formula

Comment: there is no field of s.no i table i create this my own through this line  select Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS 'RowNumber', –